# In $\sigma (12)\sigma ^{-1}=\left(\sigma (1)\sigma (2)\right)=(23)$, why $\left(\sigma (1)\sigma (2)\right)=(23)$？

Tags: group-theory, permutations

This is a proof of a formula in a math class. There are some parts that I don't quite understand, so I would like to ask for some clarification.

In $\sigma (12)\sigma ^{-1}=\left(\sigma (1)\sigma (2)\right)=(23)$, can anyone prove why the result is equal to the transposition (23)?

Sorry, the $\sigma = (12...n)$.

Comment: What is $\sigma$? Can you edit your question to add more details and context that makes it clear, because as stated, there is no reason for it to be that?

Comment: Oh, thanks. The $\sigma = (12...n)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first statement,  $\sigma (12)\sigma ^{-1}=(\sigma (1)\sigma (2))$ is always true.

The last part,  $=(23)$, needn't be true at all.   But it will be true,  by the first part,  if and only if $\sigma (1)=2$ and $\sigma (2)=3,$ or $\sigma (1)=3$ and $\sigma (2)=2.$

Thus if we are working in $\mathscr S_3$, we *must* have $\sigma =(123)$ or $\sigma =(13).$

Otoh, if we are working in $\mathscr S_{100}$, there's $2×98!$ permutations $\sigma $ out of $100!$ that will have the same effect.

Comment: Yes, very much feel your answer. I suddenly reacted to the fact that was simply substituting the results.